# How does one quantum object know of the existence of the other slit in the double slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

My question is one for basic understanding of this problem.

How can one quantum object interfere with itself? Does it know that there are two slits trough which it can pass trough?

Comment: [Relevant](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/double-slit-experiment?sort=votes&pageSize=30) stuff.

Comment: a lack of efforts but the question is clear

Answer (score 1):

When one goes to dimensions of order of microns and less the intuition of how objects  behave garnered from our everyday experience and modeled by classical mechanics and electromagnetism no longer holds.

The theory of quantum mechanics developed to explain  the inconsistencies with classical mechanics with a new theory, mathematical model.

> How can one quantum object interfere with itself?

This is wrong within quantum mechanics. The "particle", let us say electron, does not interfere with itself. The *Probability*  of finding the electron at a particular (x,y) on screen has a sinusoidal distribution. The [accumulation of many electrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles) shows up the probability distribution

[image: singleledblslit]

> Electron buildup over time

The electron appears as a dot on the screen , whole. The accumulation shows interference.

> Does it know that there are two slits trough which it can pass trough?

The quantum mechanical solution of the boundary value problem "electron scattering on two slits" *knows* there are two slits, because they are part of the boundary conditions imposed on the solution.

To attribute "knowledge" to an electron is a metaphysical position.

Answer (score 0):

First, something is clearly aware of the other slit. We know this because if we block off one slit while the experiment is going on, the diffraction pattern stops and we get the effect of the "one-slit experiment". Second, the pattern obtained through sending sufficient particles through is consistent with the diffraction pattern obtained from a wave with the wavelength consistent with the de Broglie formula pλ = h. The third point is that a single particle is detected as a point. This is important because one detection involved C60 molecules (Arndt, M., and 5 others. 1999. Wave–particle duality of C60 molecules. Nature 401: 680-682.) 
Now, either there is a wave that went through both slits or there is not. Suppose there is no wave, which is effectively what modern QM tends to assert. Either the particle goes through both slits or it does not. Modern QM tends to assert the particle is really a field, and the field "knows" about both slits, and the particle is "realised" as an excitation on observation. Personally, I find that intolerable as an explanation, because how can there be a field of C60 molecules? Similarly, if C60 molecules each go through two slits, they have to break up. How can they reassemble into one molecule, because  we know they too are detected as points?

If there is a wave, there is no mystery at all. The wave goes through both slits, the particle through one on a trajectory just as you might expect, and Bohm, in his pilot wave theory, predicted the pattern that would be obtained. Kocsis et al (Kocsis, S. and 6 others. 2011. Observing the Average Trajectories of Single Photons in a Two-Slit Interferometer Science 332: 1170 – 1173.) carried out a weak detection of photons and found they followed Bohm's prediction precisely. In my opinion, that is fairly strong support for there being a wave.

I should add a warning. I have published an ebook wherein I take the pilot wave but modify it significantly by adding two extra constraints. The first is from Euler - the wave function should become real at the antinode. (That applies to most standard wave functions.) The second is that the wave has to travel the same velocity as the particle to affect it in the two-slit experiment, which now requires the wave to transmit energy, which is what waves generally do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Much of the beauty of the double slit experiments are how effective they are at challenging your intuitions.  The whole point of the double slit experiment is that things like photons and electrons, that we would like to think of as particles, are not always well modeled as particles.  If we try to model them as simply classical particles, we end up with predictions which are not consistent with the experimentally observed results.

The double slit experiment demonstrates that these "objects" must have behaviors that are not typically associated with particles.  In fact, it turns out that waves describe the results seen quite well.  You don't worry about the fact that a wave of water can travel through two slits and interact with itself on the other side.

It gets a bit hairy when you get to the single-electron or single-photon double slit experiments.  In these experiments, we have electrons or photons which have been shown to behave as quantized packets that cannot be split between the slits, and yet we still see behaviors which are associated with wave mechanics.  This is what bugs people about the double slit experiments: we know we have a thing which must be quantized and cannot be split, and yet the results of the experiment demonstrate that it must be split.

We have not demonstrated that we can break the laws of physics: we have demonstrated that our simplification of the world into particles and waves is not valid in these sorts of experiments.  The "photon" or "electron" appears to demonstrate both wave and particle behaviors simultaneously.

Once the double slit experiment opens one's mind that physics may not line up quite as easily as it did in classical physics, one can begin searching for alternate models of what a "photon" is.  Quantum Mechanics is a set of theories which define what a "photon" is in such a way that they can mathematically predict obscure effects like those seen in the double slit experiments.  The whole point is that they *will* behave in ways that you didn't think of before when you start looking at the corner cases.  In fact, often the results predicted by these theories are so non-intuitive that we start to apply anthropomorphic terminology in explaining them, such as your use of the phrase "Does it know..."

So use this experiment as a tool to remind you to check your classical models for what the universe is at the door.  They will provide you with new quantum models which do a better job of predicting what we see in the universe around us.

Answer (score 0):

In your question there’s a pre-assumption that a quantum object is authentically a rigid particle as it was also assumed in the Classical Physics.  But the Quantum Mechanics (QM) has shown the fallacy of this assumption since the 1930s.  So, any real quantum object, by the QM definition, is both wave and particle, and this is called the “Wave-Particle Duality”.  Furthermore, recent theories like the Transactional Interpretation of QM, show that the waveform is the only real authentic nature of any quanta as long as it does not interact with any other quanta.

Taking this as our guideline hereby entails that as long as any quanta is passing-by near slits or through them, without interacting with the particles of the slits’ construction, those quanta remain in their waveforms.  As we already know from the Classical Physics waveforms like the water waves, etc, that it’s the very nature of any waveform to “know” beforehand how many slits or free passages are available to it, because any wave is spread spatially and theoretically limitlessly in its traveling medium.  This is possibly how also an quantum object (in its authentic waveform) “knows” of the other slit in the double slit experiment.